# Trigger a JTable cell edit on mouse release instead of mouse pressed event

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

In its original implementation, a `JTable` takes mouse events and if a cell is editable and the user clicks twice on it, an edit is triggered. The way I implemented the table's `DefaultCellEditor` is so that the edit occurs after a single click. This makes selecting cells by dragging the mouse up/down impossible because whenever I click on any cell, an edit event occurs. I could probably solve this by forcing the `DefaultCellEditor` to react to mouse released events only instead of mouse pressed, but I don't know how.

The first thing that I did was print the already active mouse listeners in the table.

```
for (MouseListener mouseListener : uiTable.getMouseListeners()) {
        System.out.println(mouseListener.getClass());
}
```

This gave me:

```
class javax.swing.ToolTipManager
class javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler
```

I'm assuming the answer lays with the `BasicTableUI$Handler` one. Perhaps a delegate of sorts? I'm not really sure.

Test code:

```
public class TableSO extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TableSO() {
        initComponents();
        makeUI();
    }

    public void makeUI() {
        ((DefaultCellEditor) uiTable.getDefaultEditor(String.class)).setClickCountToStart(1);
        createEditor();
    }

    public void createEditor() {
        for (MouseListener mouseListener : uiTable.getMouseListeners()) {
            System.out.println(mouseListener.getClass());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                        
    private void initComponents() {

        scrTable = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        uiTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(getContentPane(), javax.swing.BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        uiTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null},
                {null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Object.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        scrTable.setViewportView(uiTable);

        getContentPane().add(scrTable);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }                    

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new TableSO().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrTable;
    private javax.swing.JTable uiTable;                
}
```

Comment: `This makes selecting cells by dragging the mouse up/down impossible because whenever I click on any cell, an edit event occurs` - Maybe you can add a MouseMotionListener to the table and in the mouseDragged event you stop cell editing?

Comment: Very creative. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you, camickr.